# forever start not working

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I am using following command:
`/usr/local/bin/forever start /var/www/html/test.js  | tee /tmp/forever-start.log`

But it doesn't work. Not printing output in log file.

In `test.js` I have this code:
`console.log('Server running...');`

Answer (score 0):

Is the executable literaly named `forever start`?

If so, then replace `forever start` with `forever\ start`.

Comment: getting this error: `forever start: command not found`

Comment: @PathikVejani Remove the `tee` and see

Comment: @PathikVejani Remove everything after `... test.js`.

Comment: nothing happnes

Comment: It seems that the JS is not printing to standard output (`stdout`).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37045/discussion-between-bharadwaj-raju-and-pathik-vejani).